# Simplifying regular expression from two steps to one step

Tags: regex, python-2.7, ironpython

I have the following string:

```
my_line = 'ps_args: com26:57600,    19-1125063, 1234, abc'
```

and I would like the final result to be a list such as:

```
['com2:57600', 19-1125063', '1234', 'abc']
```

I getting the results I want doing the following:

```
match_PSargs = re.findall ('ps_args:\s*([-\w:,\s]+)+\s*', my_line)
#match_PSargs = ['com26:57600,    19-1125063, 1234, abc'] 

if match_PSargs: 
        print 'PSargs match_found>', match_PSargs                        
        temp = re.findall('([-\w:]+)', match_PSargs[0])
        #temp = ['com26:57600', '19-1125063', '1234', 'abc']
        print 'temp>', temp
```

Is there a way to obtain the desired result with only one regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern

```
([^ ,]+)(?:,|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/398)

```
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  [^ ,]         # Character not in [ ,] Character Class
  +             # (one or more)(greedy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
(?:             # Non Capturing Group
  ,             # ","
  |             # OR
  $             # End of string/line
)               # End of Non Capturing Group
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand effect of non-capturing group on the first item of the returned list. Removing non-capturing group from pattern, findall  includes **'ps_args:'** in the list. Including it removes **'ps_args'** from list. Is it possible to modify pattern to not match if **my_line = 'pointIndex:   24'**?

Comment: The effect of non-capturing group is the match has to be followed by a comma or end of line, as for `pointIndex: 24`, just use another step to make sure `my_line` has commas before applying regex.